# Global shared data between different instances of a Node.js native addon?

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon, node-addon-api

I'm looking to create a native addon with Node-API (more specifically with the C++ wrapper module `node-addon-api`).

I need to have global *read-only* data that will be loaded once and will be shared between different instances of the addon (e.g. when the addon is loaded by different node.js workers).

Is there a recommended way to do this? Would it be safe to just store the data in a static variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of your data. If your data does not involve any V8 data types (or Napi:: types), then, yes, it is generally safe.

Just be careful to not shared a variable that has been initialized with `Node::Env` - this is the rule to follow - if it needs `Node::Env` then it can't be shared.